# Order of an element in cycle permutation

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

Attached is an IB question on Sets, Relations and Groups. I'd like somebody to explain how to do the d) part. Though I understand that the LCM of a disjoint cycle equals the cycle's order, how do they say the LCM of 2, 3 and 5 is the order? Specifically, where did they get the 2, 3 and 5 from? Which cycle's lengths are 2, 3, 5.

I've attached both the question and the answer from the marking scheme.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is not the best way, but I suspect a way of solving this is to consider that since there are 10 elements in $H$, we know that the cycles $c_i$ of any $q \in H$ must satisfy $\sum |c_i| = 10$ (let $|c_i|$ denote the order of a cycle).

We see then to maximise the order of $q$ we must maximise the orders of the cycles. In effect, this is equivalent to maximising the product of a set of coprime numbers whose sum is 10. We then can just try, to see that

a cycle of order 10 leads to an order of 10,

cycles of orders 9, 1 lead to an order of 9,

8, 2 leads to 8,

7, 3 leads to 21,

6, 4 leads to 12,

6, 3 leads to 6

5, 5 leads to 5,

5, 3, 2 leads to 30,

etc.

Since we get many repetitions of factors after this we know we can't get any larger, so 30 must be it.

Hopefully that works?